# Find cells containing a X, and sum values of cells adjacent to cells containing X

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with one column containing URLs, and another column containing pageviews. These urls are parametized, so many of them are just different variations pointing to the same page. What I would like to do is count the total number of pageviews for pages in which a given parameter occurred.

Here is an example of the spreadsheet:

```
    Page                                                Pageviews

    /...?f_rec=true&f_tfa=15000&cid=15000               2
    /...?lvl=8&cid=9000                                 3
    /...?f_rec=true&f_tfa=15000&lvl=8                   7
```

For instance, every time the parameter "cid" occurs in a url, I would like to count the number of pageviews. In this example it occurs two times, in urls that have 2 and 3 pageviews respectively. So the total pageviews for the parameter "cid" would be 5. For the parameter "f_rec" the total pageviews would be 9, and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved but for want of an answer as such:

`=SUMIF(A:A,"*cid*",B:B)` to search for ColumnA contains `cid` and where it does add up Pageviews.
`=SUMIF(A:A,"*f_rec*",B:B)` to search for ColumnA contains `f_rec` and where it does add up Pageviews.

[=SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx).